# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (WPF Entityframework)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm new for entity framework.
Now, I'm writing the delete function with a button. When I click this button, my data will be deleted; however, it will popup the alert that 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' I can't figure out this question.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (UserDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
                    return;
                if (UserDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Would you want to delete？", "Yes", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        var selected = UserDataGrid.SelectedItem as User;
                        var index = selected.Index;

                        User user = new User();
                        user = ssEntities.User.Where(x => x.Index == index).First();

                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            ssEntities.User.DeleteObject(user);
                            ssEntities.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
            finally { }
        }
```

If there is not enough information, plz tell me to add it.

Comment: what is the line that is throwing the exception?

Comment: better yet, do you see the *"Would you want to delete?"* message box before you get the exception?

Comment: w/o the line #, my guess would be either UserDataGrid is null or it's selected item is or is not convertible to User

Comment: It's so strange that my program did not go to the catch function.

Comment: As roel says, it's not UserDataGrid if you see the message box

Comment: @Roel Yes, the message box has shown up.

Comment: In visual studio, it can be setup to stop on exception.

Comment: @kenny I'm sure that UserDataGrid is not null, and the selected item has been deleted.

Comment: @CYB it most definitely goes to the `catch` block, because the popup shows the exception message.

Comment: @Roel I also hope it goes to the `catch` block, but I have checked the interrupted point. The popup shows the exception message between the deleteobject and savechanges.

Comment: @CYB, hmm in that case, is there an override of the `DeleteObject` on the `User` entity?

Comment: @Roel No, I did not write override function, so I feel strange about this. The most strange is that the data was still deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering your comments, here is what you should do:

Since it looks like all your `try-catch` block are written as follows

```
try { }
catch (Exception ex)
{ MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
finally { }
```

you have absolutely no idea where the exception is occurring, because you are losing the whole StackTrace. You should change this behavior, as there are a lot of problems with this. Find **all** the code-blocks which use this pattern and change it to something like this:

```
try { }
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("An exception has occurred in <some function>: {0}\n{1}", ex.Message, ex));
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
}
finally { }
```

This way, you will be able to see more detailed output in your Debug window, and you should be able to locate the exact exception by inspecting the StackTrace.
Off course, instead of using `Debug.WriteLine`, you could also use another logging mechanism like `log4net`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have checked the breakpoint. It does not go to the `catch` block, and even  not show up on the Debug window.

Comment: But have you changed *all* of the code blocks which use this try-catch block? The fact that this specific breakpoint never gets hit means that the exception occurs somewhere else.

Comment: Hey, @Roel Thanks for your advise. Now, I have known where I get wrong. I just have an excess column in my datagrid, so when I add it or delete it; it will get wrong.